# vba refer to range in different workbook with "Cells()"

Tags: vba, range

i want to refer to a range in a different book, that is defined from 
this works:

```
Workbooks(macrofilename).Sheets(IDsheetname).Activate
lookRange = Range(Cells(startrow, startcol), Cells(rows, cols))
colno = Application.Match(myName, lookRange, 0)
```

but i don't want to activate the other sheet so i tried it to add the workbook&sheet to the range definition:

```
lookRange = Workbooks(filename).Sheets(sheetname).Range(Cells(startrow, startcol), Sheets(Cells(rows, cols))
```

sadly, this results in in a 1004 error (application-defined or object-defined error).

any ideas how to solve this?

thanx, Gijs.

Answer (score 2):

You can try first make reference to worksheet:

```
Dim Ws As Worksheet
Set Ws =  Workbooks(filename).Sheets(sheetname)
```

And then make reference to range:

```
With Ws
    Set rLookRange = Range(.Cells(startrow, startcol), .Cells(rows, cols))
End With
```

Pay attention on dots: you refer to Cells in specific Worksheet, so paste dots before  .Cells in your statement.

Answer (score 0):

You don't need to activate the workbook / worksheet. 
Use the "Set" keyword to define a range.

The syntax would be something like:

```
dim rLookRange as Range


set rLookRange = Workbooks(filename).Sheets(sheetname).Range(Cells(startrow, startcol), Cells(rows, cols))
```

Depending on what you want to do (?)
For comparing ranges, I usually define arrays and compare the values inside these arrays.

Comment: The calls to `Cells` will refer to the active worksheet and not to `Workbook(filename).Sheets(sheetname)` Better would be `With Workbook(filename).Sheets(sheetname) ... Set rLookRange = .Range(.Cells(...), .Cells(...))... End With`